# How to remove Pinned shortcuts after uninstalling app

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

I've added a shortcut to home screen using this code. It works fine but when I uninstall the app, added shortcuts are not removed automatically.

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://some.url/path"); 
    shortcutIntent.setData(uri);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "name");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, 
                      Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, 
                                          R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); 
    addIntent.setAction(ACTION_INSTALL_SHORTCUT);
    context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Am I missing something obvious?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There's (by design) no way for application to detect when it's uninstalled. And why do you think this particular shortcut must be removed by the system automatically?

Comment: Hi @SargeBorsch Thanks for the reply.

I think there is no use in retaining the shortcuts after uninstalling the app. Shortcut anyway going to open some component in the app. When there is no app shortcut can't do anything. It will simply show "App not found" message.